# Adding custom events to ASP controls

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, event-handling

I'm building a website using ASP and C# and I wanted to know if it's possible to add a custom events to an asp control.

I want to add an OnClick, OnMouseDown, OnMouseUp (etc.) event to `<asp:image>`.

Is it possible?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

yes you can do it this way.

**HTML**

```
 <asp:Image runat="server" ID="Image1"  />
```

**CODE BEHIND**

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e){

        this.Image1.Attributes.Add("onmouseup", "alert('this is the OnMouseUp event')");

    }
```

**EDIT**

```
  It can be do it using DHTML but as you may know 
  DHTML is the art of combining HTML, JavaScript, DOM, and CSS.

  protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e){
        //change the Image Url when the click event fire
        this.Image1.Attributes.Add("onclick", "this.src='image1.jpg'");

    }
```

Comment: Is there any way to do it without JavaScript?

Comment: @lsxliron yes you can use DHTML to add event to the html elments and react to this events.

Answer (score 0):

Note that mouse events may be impractical to be handled on the server, It's better for them to be handled locally (quicker) on the client, so the network speed does not have an impact on how fast your event is processed.